# JSCEP-Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'org.spongycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest', required: 'org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest'

Tags: java, bouncycastle, spongycastle, scep, jscep

I'm implementing Jscep for android. Initially, I tried Jscep for java and it worked fine. Now in Android, I used SpongyCastle instead of BouncyCastle. Now my problem is that the enrol method of Client class is using BouncyCastle. And so when I try to pass in the arguments, the spongycastle and bouncycastle are not fitting (obviously).

The following extends spongycastle.

```
        PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder crb = generateCSR(keyPair,entity);
```

I'm passing the above variable 'crb' as the third argument to enrol method as below.

```
try {
            response = client.enrol(cert, keyPair.getPrivate(), crb.build(getContentSigner(keyPair)), "MDM-ROOT-CA");
        }
```

And I'm getting the following error. "Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'org.spongycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest', required: 'org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest".

I tried to extend the Client, but it's declared final.

My question is "Should I switch back to BouncyCastle jars?".
Or else "How can I pass this spongycastle variable?"

Comment: Don't use spongycastle, use bouncycastle. As long as your minimum SDK is Android 4.0 they should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is "Should I switch back to BouncyCastle jars?". Or else "How can I pass this spongycastle variable?"

Probably neither will work on on all Android platforms

From what I have seen, Jscep works with (genuine) BouncyCastle not SpongyCastle.

If I read [this old issue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jscep/issues/43) correctly, the cut-down version of BouncyCastle in pre-3.0 Android is missing functionality that Jscep needs.

- For pre-3.0 Android their doesn't appear to be a practical solution.  You can't just tell Java to treat those two types as equivalent.  It would break the JVM / Davlik runtime type system.
- According to [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340829), in 3.0 Android changed the Java package name on their cut-down BouncyCastle.  That means that you should be able to bundle genuine BouncyCastle JARs with a 3.0+ Android app.  That should be sufficient to get Jscep to work on that platform.

  This [SpongyCastle issue comment](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/issues/34#issuecomment-292687789) says that the trick to getting Android to use the genuine BouncyCastle functionality is:

  > ... call `Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)` to remove the built-in BC before calling `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())`.
- In theory, it should be possible to port Jscep to use SpongyCastle, but there are no clear indications that anyone has *succeeded* in doing this.  (Given the previous, the need for such a port is only diminishing.)

Also, I couldn't find a free-standing alternative to the Jscep that worked on Android.  However, I did find this:

- https://github.com/boeboe/be.boeboe.spongycastle/blob/master/src/be/boeboe/spongycastle/jscep/JScepClient.java

which might be useful.

Comment: Using bouncycastle jars should work on any version of Android after 3.0. That is, include the jars in your project, don't try to use the built-in BC classes. See https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/issues/34#issuecomment-292687789

Comment: Hey, wait a minute, you already wrote an answer elsewhere about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52013928/238704

Comment: Fixed. Thanks.  I don't always remember what I researched 2 years ago :-)